# matlab "memory" function on mac?

Tags: memory, matlab

On Windows machines, MATLAB users can use either the [`memory`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/memory.html) or the [`feature memstats`](http://www.mathworks.com/support/tech-notes/1100/1107.html#_Toc170182661) commands. However, neither of these work on a machine, failing as follows:

```
>> memory
??? Error using ==> memory
Function MEMORY is not available on this platform.

>> feature memstats
??? Error using ==> feature
An unknown feature was specified
```

Does anyone know of a way to access information about in-matlab memory usage on a Mac?

Comment: See also this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5932598.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have not been able to find a command that reproduces the functionality of `memory`. However, if you know how much total memory your system has, you can use [`who`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/who.html) (or [`vsize`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/12278-vsize-a-pedestrian-variable-decoder) from the file exchange for more detail) to estimate how much memory your variables are currently using and thus how much free space you have.

By the way, you can always find out about Java memory by calling

```
java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime.maxMemory
java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime.totalMemory
java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime.freeMemory
```

Note that Matlab memory and Java memory are different - Java memory is used for UI, including figures, as well as other java objects, while `memory` reports the memory available for variables and calculations.

Comment: Unfortunately, neither this answer nor the one by @philippe let me see how much is allocated to matlab, how much is being used by the matlab engine, or ensure that the memory is contiguous, all of which are factors ( [link](http://www.mathworks.com/support/tech-notes/1100/1106.html)). However, this a pretty good workaround.

Comment: @eykanal: The linux systems have traditionally had better memory management (though Windows seems to have improved a lot recently), so size of largest block was mostly an issue in Windows. However, the IMHO real issue with not knowing the amount of memory on a Mac has been that you don't know when you start paging.

Comment: Well, that, and that Matlab apparently only uses [a subset of available memory](http://www.mathworks.com/support/tech-notes/1100/1107.html), depending on whether it's a 32- or 64-bit architecture. I'm dealing with very large datasets so that makes a significant difference.

Comment: @eykanal: On a 32-bit OS, a single program cannot address more than ~3GB of RAM (unless you start doing lots of tricks), so I don't see that as a Matlab-specific issue. Note that on MacOSX, it doesn't matter whether you boot the 32-bit or the 64-bit kernel, the 64-bit Matlab can address all the memory you have.

Comment: Thanks, as I was writing my last reply, I realized that I'm using a 32-bit version Matlab (2009a). I'm upgrading to the 2010 version now, so hopefully all will be good. Thanks!

Comment: @Jonas, if I understood it correctly, the results of the physical available memory, i.e: `[user,sys] = memory;sys.PhysicalMemory.Available` should be equal to `java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime.freeMemory`?, I compared both values but they appear to be different to me. How could I obtain the same value as the `sys.PhysicalMemory.Available`?

Comment: @Tin: That is not correct. Matlab manages the java memory (used for UI, including figures, as well as other java objects) separately from the memory that is available for variables and calculations.

Comment: @Jonas, thank you for the clarification. Was wondering then what does the following exactly does? `[~, sys] = memory; min(sys.PhysicalMemory.Available/304/10,100000)`? Didn't understand what `304` means?

Comment: @Tin: No idea either.Where did you get that line from?

Answer (score 1):

`memory` is only available on Windows systems.

You can try using `top` built-in Mac command instead.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old and already answered, but for anyone else looking for this answer, an alternative that works on all platforms it to use whos:

```
allvars = whos;
memused = sum([allvars.bytes]);
```

This assumes you only have one workspace being used by your script/function. If you have a script that uses multiple workspaces, you'll need to specify all the different workspaces and add them together.