# How to check available memory in Matlab 2010b or later on Mac OSX?

Tags: macos, matlab, memory, memory-management

I've got a copy of Matlab from 2004 (forgot what the version number would be, but it certainly is old), and I could use the "features memstat" command to see how much memory is available to Matlab. The command no longer works for me in Matlab 2010b, what should I do to see available memory? Thanks.

P.S. I tried the "memory" command as suggested by @Rasman but got the following error:

> ??? Error using ==> memory Function
>   MEMORY is not available on this
>   platform.

I am running Matlab 2010b for Mac OS X 64-bit.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `unix('vm_stat');` in MATLAB on a Mac. This gives, for example:

```
Mach Virtual Memory Statistics: (page size of 4096 bytes)
Pages free:                        1580152.
Pages active:                       184679.
Pages inactive:                      64572.
Pages speculative:                   63389.
Pages wired down:                   203816.
"Translation faults":              3906655.
Pages copy-on-write:                301846.
Pages zero filled:                 1899205.
Pages reactivated:                       0.
Pageins:                            107102.
Pageouts:                                0.
Object cache: 15 hits of 32166 lookups (0% hit rate)
```

Results are in pages of 4096 bytes, so multiply results by 4096 and you get values consistent with Activity Monitor (you have to add 'speculative' to 'free' to get exact agreement). If you just want the available memory, you can use `unix('vm_stat | grep free');`. If you want a number you could use something like:

```
[s,m]=unix('vm_stat | grep free');
spaces=strfind(m,' ');
str2num(m(spaces(end):end))*4096
```

EDIT: in response to a comment below "It doesn't tell you how much MATLAB used up and how much more MATLAB can use." Here is what I do for that additional question.

From my experience, 64 bit MATLAB can use up all of the free memory (and more but it slows down a lot if you start swapping much). One of my systems has 22Gb and it has no trouble using all of that. If you're using 32 bit MATLAB you're limited to 2Gb.

To see the total memory, you can add up 'free'+'active'+inactive'+'speculative'+'wired' from `vm_stat` (and multiply by 4096). Or, if you just want the total memory, you can use `unix('sysctl hw.memsize | cut -d: -f2')` (in bytes).

To get the memory used by MATLAB, is slightly more involved. The memory is used by the controlling process. If you just use `unix('ps')`, you'll get the memory used by `matlab_helper`. So I use:

```
% get the parent process id
[s,ppid] = unix(['ps -p $PPID -l | ' awkCol('PPID') ]); 
% get memory used by the parent process (resident set size)
[s,thisused] = unix(['ps -O rss -p ' strtrim(ppid) ' | awk ''NR>1 {print$2}'' ']); 
% rss is in kB, convert to bytes 
thisused = str2double(thisused)*1024
```

Above I've used a little `awk` function which picks off a named column:

```
function theStr = awkCol(colname)
theStr  = ['awk ''{ if(NR==1) for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) { if($i~/' colname '/) { colnum=i;break} } else print $colnum }'' '];
```

A little tutorial of the `unix` command to explain the above, in case it helps anyone. `unix('command')` on its own shows you the output and returns the status. If you want to process the output, use `[s,w] = unix('command')` and deal with the string output in `w`. If you want to ignore the `s` output, in later versions of MATLAB, you can use `[~,w] = unix('command')`, but I avoid that since I inevitably have different versions on different computers.

Comment: wait... this is just the system memory stats. It doesn't tell you how much MATLAB used up and how much more MATLAB can use.

Comment: @d'o-o'b: see an extended answer above.

Answer (score -3):

have you tried [memory](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/memory.html)

Comment: I tried and got this error: "??? Error using ==> memory
Function MEMORY is not available on this platform.". I am running Matlab 2010b in Mac OS X, does that matter? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: "The memory function is currently available on Microsoft Windows systems only. Results vary, depending on the computer running MATLAB, the load on that computer, and what MATLAB is doing at the time." That kindda sux. But then, I hear Mac OS' version of Matlab is significantly slower

Comment: @thorpe, it's in the documentation (under the tips header)

Comment: @thorpe if you're referring to the slower bit, it's somewhat anecdotal as I know someone with a bootcamp system, and he notices the Windows version is faster then the Mac. You can run `bench` to see where your computer is on the scale