# How to store giant matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm using a matlab script to create and store a large matrix of floating point numbers.  When I tried running this program on my personal laptop, the program ended hours later with the message 'out of memory'.  Supposedly, Matlab has a limit for the maximum-sized array it can store, which makes sense.

My question is:  how to store large matrix in matlab?  Specifically, I'm using a 64-bit linux OS, and I need to store a 5-6 GB matrix.

Comment: If you have enough RAM this should not be a problem. Apparently you don’t have enough RAM to store this matrix?

Comment: How can I find out how much RAM my computer has?

Comment: That depends on your OS, there is usually a system information applet somewhere. See also this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5932598/how-to-check-available-memory-in-matlab-2010b-or-later-on-mac-OS X

Comment: Read about memory function in matlab. This will show you how much data your MATLAB can handle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not an expert in this, but as I understand it the most simple solution would be to get more RAM. However, you could try to check the available memory at the time of the error with

```
dbstop if error 
memory
```

This should tell you how much Memory is available for Matlab, how much is currently used and how large your biggest array can be. If you exceed this I don't think there is a software solution for that besides storing the data in multiple smaller files.

If you get the "Out of memory: Java Heap Space" error you can increase the memory which is available for Java under (Home -> Preferences -> General -> Java Heap Memory)

Also check if your array side is limited to a certain percentage of your available memory under (Home -> Preferences -> Workspace -> MATLAB array size limit) and set it to 100%.

[Similar question in Matlab forum](https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/153250-out-of-memory-help-needed)