# Matlab: your opinion about a small memory issue working with matrix

Tags: matlab, double, ram, bsxfun

I have a small question regarding MATLAB memory consumption.

My Architecture:
- Linux OpenSuse 12.3 64bit
- 16 GB of RAM
- Matlab 2013a 64 bit

I handle a matrix of **double** with size: 62 x 11969100 (called y)

When I try the following:

```
a = bsxfun(@minus,y,-1)
```

or simply

```
a = minus(y, -1)
```

I got a **OUT of MEMORY error** (in both cases).

I've just computed the ram space allocated for the matrix:
62 x 11969100 x 8 = **5.53 GB**

Where am I wrong?!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: what is the output of `memory` command? it might be the case you do not have enough contiguous memory for the result matrix `a`

Comment: Hi Shai, I work on linux machine, so `memory` command does not work unfortunately.

Comment: What? I'm not familiar with this issue... Typing `>> memory` on Matlab's command window does not give you any output?

Comment: See doc for [`memory`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/memory.html)

Comment: `>> memory
Error using memory
Function MEMORY is not available on this platform.`

Comment: `>> help memory The memory function is currently available on PCWIN and PCWIN64 only.`

Comment: The lazy @$#%^rs on Matlab...

Comment: If you are not too picky about accuracy, try replacing `double` variables with `single` ones - you get factor x2 on mem...

Comment: Actually, the modern definition of MB is 1e6 bytes, while the MiB is defined as 1024*1024 (same for all multipliers). Therefore, `62*11969100*8/1e9 = 5.94 GB`.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin: What do you mean exactly?

Comment: Shai: Yes, for some applications it is fine, but for some others I need precision 8 bit @Rody: Actually my calculation was: 62*11969100*8/(1024^3) = 5.529GB, is a modern definition better or just convinient?!

Comment: @user2389160: Have a look [here](http://xkcd.com/394/).

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis Best explanation EVER

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm running on Win64, with 16GB RAM.

Starting with a fresh MATLAB, with only a couple of other inconsequential applications open, my baseline memory usage is about 3.8GB. When I create `y`, that increases to 9.3GB (9.3-3.8 = 5.5GB, about what you calculate). When I then run `a = minus(y, -1)`, I don't run out of memory, but it goes up to about 14.4GB.

You wouldn't need much extra memory to have been taken away (1.6GB at most) for that to cause an out of memory error.

In addition, when MATLAB stores an array, it requires a contiguous block of memory to do so. If your memory was a little fragmented - perhaps you had a couple of other tiny variables that happened to be stored right in the middle of one of those 5.5GB blocks - you would also get an out of memory error (you can sometimes avoid that issue with the use of `pack`).

Answer (score 1):

The output of `memory` on windows platform:

```
>> memory
Maximum possible array:            2046 MB (2.145e+009 bytes) *
Memory available for all arrays:   3226 MB (3.382e+009 bytes) **
Memory used by MATLAB:              598 MB (6.272e+008 bytes)
Physical Memory (RAM):             3561 MB (3.734e+009 bytes)

*  Limited by contiguous virtual address space available.
** Limited by virtual address space available.
```

The output of `computer` on linux/mac:

```
>> [~,maxSize] = computer
maxSize =
     2.814749767106550e+14    % Max. number of elements in a single array
```

with some hacks (found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4762044/matlab-memory-function-on-mac)):

```
>> java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime.maxMemory
ans =
    188416000  

>> java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime.totalMemory
ans =
    65011712

>> java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime.freeMemory
ans =
    57532968
```

As you can see, aside from memory limitations per variable, there are also limitations on total storage for *all* variables. This is not different for Windows or Linux.

The important thing to note is that for example on my Windows machine, it is impossible to create two 1.7GB variables, even though I have enough RAM, and neither is limited by maximum variable size.

Since carrying out the `minus` operation will assign a result of equal size to a new variable (`a` in your case, or `ans` when not assigning to anything), there need to be at least *two* of these humongous things in memory.

My guess is you run into the second limit of total memory space available for all variables.

Answer (score 0):

bsxfun is vectorized for efficiency. Typically vectorized solutions require more than just minimal memory.

You could try using `repmat`, or if that does not work a simple `for` loop.

In general I believe the `for` loop will require the least memory.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but still I am not convinced, the matrix is less of 6 GB and I have 16 GB on my machine.