# Handling a very big and sparse matrix in Matlab

Tags: macos, matlab, matrix, sparse-matrix

I have a very big and sparse matrix, represented as a CSV file (67 GB).

Is it possible to load and work with this matrix in Matlab? I can use a 64bit version on a MAC OS computer, 8GB RAM.

I have read a few posts about this topics but still I am not sure if Matlab 64bit on Mac OS can use the disk space for allocating the matrix or need everything in RAM and, anyway, if the use of such a big portion of disk space can make things almost unusable.

Comment: Does 67 GB includes all of the zeros? How many non-zero elements are there? What is the overall dimension of the matrix? Somewhere in the 100,000 X 100,000 range?

Comment: Yes, 67GB is the size of the CSV file including the empty elements; in order to save space, I removed the 0 so 4,0,0,7,8 becomes 4,,,7,8.
The size in term of row x col is 230k x 290k. Less than 1/1000 of the matrix (0.1%) is non-empty. Cell values are integer usually < 1000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like memory mapping is the solution for you!

http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/memory-mapping.html

In essence you map the location of a file so you can access it per part (a kind of indexing but then on your harddrive I suppose). After you have done that, depending on the sparsity (sparseness?) of the matrix, you might want to switch to a sparse matrix which hopefully fits in your RAM so you can utilize the speed of RAM and no longer be limited to HDD speeds.

Another solution would be to read the file line by line (or other delimited quantity) and put only the non-zero values in a sparse matrix.

http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/fgetl.html

http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html

Kind regards,

Ernst Jan

OK So when using the fgetl solution I get reasonable performance. Approx. 10s per 100 lines on my laptop.

```
% Start with a clean slate.
clear all
% Create a data file, large!
m = 100; % Rows
n = 230000; % Columns
max_x = 10000;
X=randi(max_x,m,n); 
% Create lots of zeros by setting everything smaller 0.999 x_max to 0;
X(X<0.999*max_x)=0;
% Write data file
csvwrite('csvlist.dat',X);

% Now create a sparse matrix to put the csv file in:
P = sparse(m,n);

% Open data file
FID=fopen('csvlist.dat','r');
% Set line number counter to 0
line_number = 0;
% Get the first line of the data file (230K numbers)
text_line = fgetl(FID);
    % If a text line has been retrieved from the line keep looping!
    tic
    while ischar(text_line)
        % Increase to line_number with 1 (MATLAB index starts at 1..)
        line_number = line_number+1;
        % Analyse the first text line (I assume all integers, otherwise change the format %d to %f)
        C = textscan(text_line,'%d','delimiter',',','EmptyValue', 0);
        % Now the number are stored in cell C. Which we should put in the
        % sparse matrix:
        P(line_number,:)=C{1}; % Can be optimized but forgot how but fast enough for now!
        % And let's get the next line!
        text_line = fgetl(FID);
    end
    toc
    fclose(FID);
```

So 230k lines should take about 5 to 10 hours.

Kind regards,

Ernst Jan

Comment: I have added some details as comments of my questions.

Comment: The sparse matrix will be a few hundred MB's I suspect. With proper data management no problem at all. Simply use the fgetl and parse the line (string type, i.e. array of chars) to fill the sparse matrix. I would suggest by writing the script and letting it run over night and then save the variable representing the sparse matrix as a .mat file for future use.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The problem I am experiencing is that Matlab returns a "Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch." error at the line
C = textscan(text_line,'%d','delimiter',',','EmptyValue', 0) unless I set n to (n-1).

I guess in this way it ignores the last char (a missing value for the last cell of a line, so ,\n). Any clue?

Comment: Well I think the problem will be in the line thereafter (P(line_number,:)=C{1}. Try to check if the length of C indeed is 230K, or that it is 229 999. Your number of values on a line must be equal to n and be constant at each line. So simply check the length of C ( n_numbers = length(C) ) before assigning it to P to identify the problem.

Comment: Yes C is 229999, but I don't understand why matlab gets the EmptyValue correctly in the middle of the line and doesn't at the end of the line. So 5,,5,3 is 4 cells, while 5,2,4, is 3 cells, why?

Comment: Ok a quick work-around is appending zero values if length(C{1}) < n. So before assigning P=C put:
if  length(C{1})< n
    C{1}(end+1:n)=0;
end
Works like a charm ;) Please accept my answer if it works :)

Comment: Thanks for the last comment. Yes, it works like that, it seems just weird to me that this bug hasn't been highlighted by anyone, I am afraid we are missing something. Also, the "EmptyValue" parameter seems to have no effect, empty values gets "All zero sparse: 1-by-1" in any case, with or without the parameter.
I will see if working with that sparse matrix is actually feasible, because I remember I had to switch back to the full matrix for some operations due to slowness of the sparse matrixes, but I accept anyway your answer because it pointed me straight to the possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this link](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/91711-what-is-the-maximum-matrix-size-for-each-platform) I would say that matlab can definitely hold the amount of data stored in the matrix on most computers. (The matrix you describe should even fit into RAM I guess). To find the limits of your computer, use the `memory` command.

That being said, the hard part in creating this matrix is reading the file. As mentioned in the answer by @EJG89, you may need to use a line by line approach with `fgetl` as I don't expect higher level commands like `dlmread` to handle such a huge file in a reasonable way.

If all else fails, just find a way to split the file before processing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and just a comment: the memory command seems not to be available on MAC OS.

Comment: `memory` is only available on Windows.

Comment: True, that topic is addressed here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4762044