# Matlab doesn't recognize empty values at the end of a CSV file line

Tags: matlab, csv

I am reading with Matlab a CSV file; the file can contain empty values which I want to convert into 0

```
FID=fopen('/file.txt','r');
text_line = fgetl(FID);
C = textscan(text_line,'%d','delimiter',',','EmptyValue', 0);
```

If the empty value is in the middle of the line, e.g.

```
5,,6
```

everything works fine and the variable C gets

```
5 0 6
```

as values. If the empty value is at the end, e.g.

```
5,6,
```

Matlab doesn't recognize it and the C variable gets

```
5 6
```

as values, instead of

```
5 6 0
```

EDIT After Dennis answer:
I don't understand why the number of elements expected is needed, I give the separator, shouldn't it be enough? Anyway I tried and the result is different: with %d%d%d I get

```
C = 

    [5]    [0x1 int32]     [6]
```

with %d everything is in the first element so

```
C{1}

ans =

           5
           0
           6
```

This code snippet is part of a procedure which import a very big CSV matrix into a matlab sparse matrix (see my post [Handling a very big and sparse matrix in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24789600/handling-a-very-big-and-sparse-matrix-in-matlab)) and I guess (not tried yet) that the first approach is faster.

Anyway, my values are actually >290k per line so I guess it wouldn't be a feasible option to specify all the %d

Comment: It is simpler if you use textscan of fscanf instead

Comment: If all your values are numeric you can use csvread - it may work better. You may also check importdata. Unfortunatelly http://abandonmatlab.wordpress.com/2012/08/07/matlab-cant-read-plain-text-data-out-of-a-wet-paper-bag/

Comment: I think csvread is slower, anyway I tried with a small subset of the matrix and something weird happens: if the number of columns is > 100k the matrix is created with just ONE column and all the values distributed in the rows. I can't understand why.
M = csvread('file.csv')

Answer (score 4):

Judging from [this answer on matlab central](http://www.mathworks.nl/matlabcentral/answers/8846-how-to-use-textscan-to-read-data-with-missing-values) you need to tell Matlab how many values you expect.

In your case I would expect this to translate to:

```
FID=fopen('/file.txt','r');
text_line = fgetl(FID);
C = textscan(text_line,'%d%d%d','delimiter',',','EmptyValue', 0);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have edited my question with more details.