# Sparse Matrix Assignment becomes very slow in Matlab

Tags: matlab, sparse-matrix

I am filling a sparse matrix P (230k,290k) with values coming from a text file which I read line by line, here is the (simplified) code

```
while ...
            C = textscan(text_line,'%d','delimiter',',','EmptyValue', 0);
            line_number = line_number+1;
            P(line_number,:)=C{1};
end
```

the problem I have is that while at the beginning the

```
P(line_number,:)=C{1};
```

statement is fast, after a few thousands lines become exterely slow, I guess because Matlab need to find the memory space to allocate every time. Is there a way to pre-allocate memory with sparse matrixes? I don't think so but maybe I am missing something. Any other advise which can speed up the operation (e.g. having a lot of free RAM can make the difference?)

Comment: By far the fastest way to generate a sparse matrix is to load all the values in at once, then generate the sparse matrix in one call to `sparse`.

However, there might be a better way to do what you need. How will you work with matrix `P` once you've read in the data?

Comment: Do you mean assigning the value to a normal matrix and then convert it in a sparse one?
I am not sue it is feasible, the matrix is very big. I am actually using the code suggested here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24789600/handling-a-very-big-and-sparse-matrix-in-matlab to fill the matrix, it appeared to be fine but, as said, after a while becomes very slow.

Comment: No, I mean reading in all the values as a vector, creating vectors of their column and row destinations, then calling `sparse` to create the sparse matrix for you in one go (see the documentation for `sparse`).

Comment: The bad thing about that technique is that you need at least four times the memory: one vector for the values, another each for the rows and columns, and then again for the sparse matrix. See http://dylan-muir.com/articles/matlab_sparse_matrices/ and http://dylan-muir.com/articles/matlab_sparse_direct/

Comment: I've finally followed your advice to crate the sparse matrix in one go, I was able to create it in less than 12h which was OK for me. Thanks. If you want you can add your comment as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By far the fastest way to generate a sparse matrix wihtin matlab is to load all the values in at once, then generate the sparse matrix in one call to `sparse`. You have to load the data and arrange it into vectors defining the row and column indices and values for each filled cell. You can then call `sparse` using the `S = sparse(i,j,s,m,n)` syntax.

Comment: If the matrix is giant, it is possible to load all data. how should we do it then?

Comment: i mean it is not possible to load all data

Comment: The bad thing about that technique is that you need at least four times the memory: one vector for the values, another each for the rows and columns, and then again for the sparse matrix. See http://dylan-muir.com/articles/matlab_sparse_matrices and http://dylan-muir.com/articles/matlab_sparse_direct

Answer (score 2):

There's a sixth input argument to [`sparse`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html) that tells the number of nonzero elements in the matrix. That's used by Matlab to preallocate:

> `S = sparse(i,j,s,m,n,nzmax)` uses vectors `i`, `j`, and `s` to generate an
>   `m`-by-`n` sparse matrix such that `S(i(k),j(k)) = s(k)`, with space
>   allocated for `nzmax` nonzeros.

So you could initiallize with

```
P = sparse([],[],[],230e3,290e3,nzmax);
```

You can make a guess about the number of nonzeros (perhaps checking file size?) and use that as `nzmax`. If it turns you need more nonzero elements in the end, Matlab will preallocate on the fly (slowly).

Comment: I have tried it, P2 = sparse([],[],[],m,n,60000000); but the value assignment is still slow after a few thousand rows, more or less the execution time is the same. So the memory allocation is not the bottleneck?

Comment: @Eugenio It would appear so. But I don't really know how Matlab allocates memory with sparse matrices